# Add 'fake' antialiasing to rotated rectangle

Tags: graphics, coronasdk, antialiasing

I'm using Corona SDK, which fairly recently disabled antialiasing, without a way to re-enable it. I have several apps that use rotated rectangles and lines, and would like a way for to not look jagged. This image shows the difference:

[image]

Is there a way to add some sort of antialiasing to these rectangles in Corona? I'd much prefer an antialias hack and be able to use new Corona features and fixes than use an old build with antialiasing.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [masks](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/setMask.html) to your rects or images, it can minimize aliasing and it's a good alternative in anti-aliasing

I test the rect without a mask, it's ugly and when I added the mask it improved the rect

```
display.newRect(0,0,320,480) --Background

local rmask = graphics.newMask( "mask.png" ) --Mask

local w = math.random(100,300) --Your random width of your rect
local h = math.random(100,300) --Your random height of your rect
local r = display.newRect(100,100,w,h) --Rect
r:setFillColor(0,0,0)
r:setMask(rmask)

--This will resize the mask to your rect's dimensions, make sure you know your mask's width and height
r.maskScaleX = w/200 --the 200 is the mask's width
r.maskScaleY = h/200 --the 200 is the mask's height

transition.to(r,{time = 100000, rotation = 360*10}) --To test the aliasing when it rotates
```

I used this mask, you can test it for yourself

[image: 200x200 mask]

Comment: That's definitely an interesting idea, I can see it does minimize aliasing. Is there a way to dynamically generate the masks? (Probably not, but the rectangles in my apps can be any random dimensions, and it would be unfeasible to create and include a mask image for each size.)

Comment: You can dynamically produced mask or images, I discovered it by using `display.save()`, this will save a display group as an image and you can use the saved image as your mask. http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/save.html

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, that's good to know. It sounds quite resource-intensive to generate a mask for each rectangle size, save it, and apply it. Might be the best option, though.

Comment: That's a great solution, I'm just trying to figure out how to get it to work with small rectangles *and* large rectangles. I think I'll have a small mask and a large mask.

Comment: Yes you can do that, I'm glad to help and I learned something too.

Comment: Isn't there a limit of 3 masks being active at a time?